# How to read only from file descriptors that have changed

Tags: c, sockets

When select returns that filw descriptors have changed, how do i only read from which sockets have data? ATM when a FD changes, the printf statement executes, even if that FD has no data in the buffer.

EDIT: The issue I'm having is read keeps reading though I'm not sending any data down it. I AM using the 1 sockets for both send an receive.

```
void receive(struct nodeData *nd, struct sockInfo *si){
char buffer[MAXBUF];
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 1000;
// ----Wait in select until file descriptors change----
int y = select(si->maxFD, &si->fd_read_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

if (y <= 0)
    return;
for (int i=0; i < nd->netTopo->n; i++) {
    /* ----Was it child i---- */
    if (FD_ISSET(si->mastFD[i], &si->fd_read_set)) {
        read(si->mastFD[i], buffer, MAXBUF);
        printf("%d %d %d \n",buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If read returned `>0`, then some data was there. Why do you think that there's "no data"? BTW, you absolutely have to store the value returned by `read`, if it's less than 3 then your code is reading garbage.

Comment: @Mat Less than 3? Huh?

Comment: To test I'm only sending data down 1 socket and the print statement prints out multiple times but it doesn't print anything if that makes sense.

Comment: @n.m.: Donatello is accessing `buffer[2]`. If `read` read 1 or 2 bytes only, that's reading garbage. Donatello: no, that's not clear at all. Please [edit] your question to show exactly what you're doing (including what you're sending), and some sample output.

Comment: I posted the code above

Comment: @Mat: Ah, OK. The program is *printing* garbage then.

Comment: @n.m.: yes, it's reading garbage from `buffer`, then printing it. The `read` itself is fine. Confusing, sorry.

Comment: @Donatello: that doesn't help. We still don't know what you're sending, how you're sending it, and what you're seeing output. I'm not sure the access of buffer past what read returned is the actual issue, you need to provide more details on the send size, and print out what read returned each time in addition to the buffer contents.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (read(si->mastFD[i], buffer, MAXBUF) > 0)
        printf("%d %d %d \n",buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2]);
```

This is going to print junk 3/4 of the time. It should be:

```
int count = read(si->mastFD[i], buffer, MAXBUF);
if (count >= 3)
    printf("%d %d %d \n",buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2]); 
else if (count == 2)
    printf("%d %d \n",buffer[0], buffer[1]); 
else if (count == 1)
    printf("%d \n",buffer[0]); 
else if (count == 0)
{
    printf("EOS on %d \n",si->mastFD[i]); 
    close(si->mastFD[i]);
}
else if (count < 0)
{
    printf("error on %d: %s \n",si->mastFD[i], strerr[errno]); 
    close(si->mastFD[i]);
}
```